# how to change window.location and then trigger an element?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.create-box').on('click', function() {
  window.location.href = "/photos/new/";
  $('input#photo_picture').focus().trigger('click');
});
```

I want to click on a button that will change the url and then trigger the input on the new page.

Comment: You need to pass something with the url (or in the post [not recommanded], or cookie) that will call the action. The trigger itself must be in the new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first page use this code for changing the page url to `/photos/new/`:

```
$('.create-box').on('click', function() {
  window.location.href = "/photos/new/";
});
```

and on target page you can focus on input with this code:

```
$('input#photo_picture').focus();
```